# How to check for existence of an element with XElement?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Notice in this code I am trying to check for the existence of the rdfs:range element before trying to select it. I do this to avoid a possible null reference exception at runtime.

```
    private readonly XNamespace rdf = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#";
    private readonly XNamespace rdfs = "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#";
    private readonly XElement ontology;

    public List<MetaProperty> MetaProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return (from p in ontology.Elements(rdf + "Property")
                    select new MetaProperty
                    {
                        About = p.Attribute(rdf + "about").Value,
                        Name = p.Element(rdfs + "label").Value,
                        Comment = p.Element(rdfs + "comment").Value,
                        RangeUri = p.Elements(rdfs + "range").Count() == 1 ?
                            p.Element(rdfs + "range").Attribute(rdf + "resource").Value :
                            null
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

This is kinda bugging me, what I really want to do is something like this:

```
p.HasElements(rdfs + "range") ?
    p.Element(rdfs + "range").Attribute(rdf + "resource").Value :
    null
```

However there is no `HasElement(string elementName)` method available.

I guess I could create a method extension to do this, but am wondering if there is something already built in or if there are other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same basic thing, but neater

```
return (from p in ontology.Elements(rdf + "Property") 
let xRange = p.Element(rdfs + "range") 
select new MetaProperty 
{ 
    About = p.Attribute(rdf + "about").Value, 
    Name = p.Element(rdfs + "label").Value, 
    Comment = p.Element(rdfs + "comment").Value, 
    RangeUri = xRange == null ? null : xRange.Attribute(rdf + "resource").Value 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this is neater. I like it, think I'll use it to do checks on some other properties also.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
p.Elements(rdfs + "range").SingleOrDefault()
```

which will return `null` if there are no elements. It will throw an exception if there's more than one matching element - `FirstOrDefault()` will avoid this if it's not the desired behaviour.

EDIT: As per my comment, and taking advantage of the conversion from XAttribute to string also handling nulls:

```
return (from p in ontology.Elements(rdf + "Property") 
        select new MetaProperty 
                   { 
                       About = p.Attribute(rdf + "about").Value, 
                       Name = p.Element(rdfs + "label").Value, 
                       Comment = p.Element(rdfs + "comment").Value, 
                       RangeUri = (string) p.Elements(rdf + "range")
                                            .Attributes(rdf + "resource")
                                            .FirstOrDefault()
                    }).ToList();
```

If you have the same thing in many places, you could write an extension method to encapsulate that very easily:

```
public static XAttribute FindAttribute(this XElement element,
    XName subElement, XName attribute)
{
    return element.Elements(subElement).Attributes(attribute).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

So the RangeUri bit would be:

```
RangeUri = (string) p.FindAttribute(rdf + "range", rdf + "resource")
```

Comment: Good to know, I forgot about the FirstOrDefault functionality. The only potential issue I see with that is that I can't just call .Attribute on it because I don't know if it will return null or not.

Comment: @Paul: True. You might want to write your own extension method `AttributeOrNull` which accepts nulls appropriately. Alternatively, you could use `Elements(rdfs + "range").Attributes(rdf + "resource").FirstOrDefault()`